# error running docker inside docker

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-compose

My development machine is OSX. I use *boot2docker* to run *docker* for my development (call this *docker-1*). My app also uses *docker* containers (so it's docker running inside docker - call this *docker-2*).

Typically I use *docker-compose* on my development machine to start up *docker-1*. The issue is that when I run

> docker-compose run web /bin/bash

and then at the *docker-1* bash prompt I try starting docker:

> service docker start

the service seems to start, creates a pid file, but dies. `/var/log/docker.log` reads:

`time="2015-05-21T12:40:23Z" level=warning msg="Udev sync is not supported. This will lead to unexpected behavior, data loss and errors"
time="2015-05-21T12:40:23Z" level=error msg="There are no more loopback devices available."
time="2015-05-21T12:40:23Z" level=info msg="+job serveapi(unix:///var/run/docker.sock)"
time="2015-05-21T12:40:23Z" level=info msg="Listening for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock)"
time="2015-05-21T12:40:23Z" level=fatal msg="Shutting down daemon due to errors: error intializing graphdriver: loopback mounting failed"`

So at first I thought this was a problem with docker. But when I start *docker-1* manually - bypassing *docker-compose* and running it like:

> docker run --privileged=true -ti website /bin/bash

and then try starting docker inside the prompt, everything works as expected:

> service docker start

succeeds - docker is started and running properly!

which makes me believe there's an issue with *docker-compose* or, more likely, something wrong with my setup. but i've gone through the manual and haven't seen anything that caught my eye.

#### docker-compose.yml

`db:
  image: postgres
  ports:
    - "5432"
redis:
  image: redis
  ports:
    - "6379"
web:
  privileged: true
  build: .
  volumes:
    - .:/app
  environment:
    - A=b
  ports:
    - "3001:3000"
  links:
    - db
    - redis`

Comment: looks like i can get this working if i restart the host. eventually it will stop working again though.

Comment: Which version of docker-compose do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will fix on OSX but when doing something like this with a CI tool that needed to run docker in docker it was now to a volume mapping.

Try adding the following to to your docker run command:

> -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock